# Photoshop 3D Cube Rounded Corners

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, 3d

I have a cube that I created in Photoshop CS6 using the 3D tools. However, I want the corners on the cube to be rounded, similar to those on dice.

How can I accomplish this?

Here is an example of what I am looking for:

[image: Cube]

Comment: Hi Jacob, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop

Choose Rounded Rectangle Tool with your desired radius and hold shift to make a perfect rounded square.

Open 3D Tools palette (Window - 3D). And create a new 3D object from the rounded rectangular shape by clicking `create`.

Then apply the 3D settings in the Repousse window, rotate your created shape using `Rotate The Mesh` tool to change the perspective of the cube.

Note: The above image was made in a 3d modeling program Cheetah3d. You will have a lot more control creating 3d objects in a 3d modeling program.

Comment: I am using CS6, and I would like to keep it a 3D object instead of rasterizing it.

Comment: I was wrong, it shouldn't ask you to rasterize the layer. Have you tried and of these steps?

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://photoshopcafe.com/photocube-tutorial.htm and want to make the corners round

Comment: Well to make a round cube, you will need to follow the steps I have written above and then apply the texture (which is step 5 in your tutorial you have linked). The preset they used in step 2 is a square cube. Please attempt the directions I have written above.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the late response. I have been traveling the last few days. I have followed your directions up until step 3. What is the repousse window? When I created the 3D object, it seems as though only the face with the rounded rectangle has rounded corners.